# Is it possible to write the '~' symbol in text in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I did not try any specific code for this, mathematical `$~$` does not work, and obviously, merely placing `~` does not work either. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need to write the tilde-like character in math mode? If so, have you given `\sim` a try? (For text mode, use `\textasciitilde`.)

Comment: $\sim$ works! Thank you!